# C# UWP async method doesn't work in service but it works in ViewModel

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I'm trying to add an item to my database. The viewmodel calls the async method from the service to add this item. But nothing happens. If I put the implementation of the method in my viewmodel class, the item gets added. What am i doing wrong?

Method from the ViewModel

```
public async Task AddCategory()
    {
        await _service.AddCategoryAsync(this.category);
    }
```

Method from the Service

```
public async Task AddCategoryAsync(Category category)
    {
        var categoryJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(category);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + App.LoggedInUser.Token);
        var res = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:49875/api/Category/"),
            new StringContent(categoryJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Category newCategory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(res.Content.ToString());
            Categories.Add(newCategory);
        }

    }
```

I tried to debug it, but the debugger doesn't get to the line 'var res...' Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried call  `Categories.Add(newCategory);` in [uithread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-19041)?

Comment: How are you calling your ViewModel.AddCategory from the View? if you're using mvvm pattern, can you post your Command? and how you initialize it?